# Regex xml matching

Tags: xml, regex

I have an xml file that looks like this:

```
...
<e1>
   <e2>
      <e3>content1.1</e3>
      <e3>content1.2</e3>
      ...
      <e3>content1.n</e3>
   </e2>
   <e2>
      <e3>content2.1</e3>
      <e3>content2.2</e3>
      ...
      <e3>content2.n</e3>
   </e2>
   ...
</e1>
...
```

I need a regex that given the xml string (a bunch of `e1` elements), would match the all `e2` elements that have a child `e3` element with content `contentx`. In other words, the regex would match all `e2` elements (could have different `e1` parents) where each of these elements has at least one `e3` child who's contents equal `contentx`.

Comment: You should use a XML-parsing library. Which language are you coding in?

Comment: Using regular expressions is not good approach for parsing XML. They have a lot of issues in this context. I highly recommend you to use XPath

Comment: Using C#. The problem with using xml parsing is that the file I'm trying to parse can contain invalid xml.

Comment: If you need to match stuff that isn't XML, why did you tell us it was XML? Matching XML using regular expressions is pretty-well impossible, matching stuff that might or might not be XML is best not even to think about.

Comment: I said it was XML to help you guys understand the format. I was looking for a regex so I didn't think that whether or not it was valid XML would matter. Sorry about the confusion. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Don't use a regex to parse XML.  Just don't do it.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)  This is precisely the sort of thing that [XPath](http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/xpath) was made to do.  I would offer an XPath expression, but I'm not completely sure what you are trying to match.

Comment: Probably something like `/e1/e2[e3='contentx']`

Comment: You're right, using XPath would probably be easier. The reason I'm trying to use a regex is that the string I'm dealing with here is actually html which might not always be valid xml. I'm coding in C# Any suggestions?

Comment: @MayadAL-Saidi - Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c